# Find the most "scattered" permutations

Tags: metric-spaces, permutations, symmetric-groups

Given $n$ and $k$, we want to find $k$ permutations that are most "scattered".

Background: I am trying to have multiple outputs using a greedy algorithm on a combinatorial optimization problem, which makes a decision for each node in a given order of the nodes. I want to have multiple trials that are as different as possible from each other. The nodes are assumed to be symmetric, and thus WLOG we can assume we always include $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, n)$.

Sorry for not having a rigorous definition.
What I have in mind is when we have a circle, say, with radius $1$, then the most "scattered" three points can be $(\sin x, \cos x), (\sin (x + 2\pi/3), \cos (x + 2\pi/3)), (\sin (x + 4\pi/3), \cos (x + 4\pi/3))$, where $x$ can take any value due to the symmetry of a circle.

What can be an analogy in the space of all permutations?

Intuitively, for $k = 2$, we may have $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, n)$ and $(n, n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1)$.

I think we need to first decide which "distance" between permutations we want to use and then build up the corresponding metric space.

Any advice or comments would be highly appreciated.

---

Update: One of my friends mentioned a concept called "Latin Rectangle" (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinRectangle.html). It seems useful to me. Would that be theoretically supported?

Comment: I can think of a few different ways to define distance between permutations. Do you have an application or some criteria that would help us choose one?

Comment: @Karl Thanks! I am trying to have multiple outputs using a greedy algorithm on a combinatorial optimization problem, which makes a decision for each node in a given order of the nodes. I want to have multiple trials that are as different as possible from each other.

Comment: Does the numeric position of the elements matter, or just their ordering? For example, consider the distances between 1234, 2134, and 3214. Is 3214 further away than 2134 from 1234? (Both are one swap away, but the elements that are swapped are different)

Comment: @AlexK Only the ordering!

Comment: Would "number of non-matching elements" be an adequate metric of distance for you? 45123 vs 15342 would be distance 4 (only 5 is in the same place)

Comment: @AlexK Thank you! But considering my applicational scenario, to 123456, 654321 and 612345 should be different.

Comment: The pairwise distances between those would be 4 (3 in the middle position), 5, and 4 (5 in start position). So they're all different